# I have a bug with my javascript for a simple game

Tags: javascript

The Bug I encountered is when I was making the collision detection system for detecting collision between the player and squares drawn using a for statement, It picks up the collisions perfectly fine I know this because I have it logging to the console whenever it detects a collision along with the side that the collision was one. But after that console log, it should stop the player movement by setting a variable I am using for movement from 10 to 0 but it isn't, Sorry for adding all the code I just have no clue as to why the problem exists in the first place

```js
var frame = setInterval(draw,10);
var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var pos = [[300,250],[500,250],[700,250]]
var height = 150;
var width = 150;
var plyr = {pos:[0,0],width: 50,height: 50};
var a = {up: 10, down:10, left:10, right:10};

function draw(){
canvas.width = canvas.width

for(var i=0;i < pos.length;i++){
  ctx.rect(pos[i][0],pos[i][1],height,width);
  ctx.stroke();
}
ctx.rect(plyr.pos[0],plyr.pos[1],plyr.width,plyr.height);
ctx.stroke();
}

document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == '38') {/*up*/plyr.pos[1] -= a.up;}
  else if (e.keyCode == '40') {/*down*/plyr.pos[1] += a.down;}
  else if (e.keyCode == '37') {/*left*/plyr.pos[0] -= a.left;d=1;}
  else if (e.keyCode == '39') {/*right*/plyr.pos[0] += 
  a.right;d=0;}

  for(var c=0;c < pos.length;c++){
    touch(plyr.pos[0],plyr.pos[1],plyr.width,plyr.height,pos[c]
    [0],pos[c][1],height,width);
  }
}


function touch(x1,y1,width1,height1,x2,y2,width2,height2){
  if( x1 + width1 > x2 && x2 + width2 > x1 && y1 + height1 > y2 && 
  y2 + height2 > y1){
    if( y1 + height1 > y2 && y2 + 20 > y1 + height1 )
    {console.log('touch down');a.down = 0;}
    else if( y2 + height2 > y1 && y1 + 20 > y2 + height2)
    {console.log('touch up');a.up = 0;}
    else if( x1 + width1 > x2 && x2 + 20 > x1 + width1)
    {console.log('touch right');a.right = 0;}
    else if( x2 + width2 > x1 && x1 + 20 > x2 + width2)
    {console.log('touch left');a.left = 0;}
  }
  else{
    a.up = 10;
    a.down = 10;
    a.left = 10;
    a.right = 10;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
      </head>
      
      <body>
        <canvas id="Canvas" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: so many conditional statements. you should try re-writing your code to make it cleaner and legible

Comment: sorry this is my first real attempt at java script and so if you could suggest another way of doing it, it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a better way to solve this, is to set the players position to the edge of the object on collision.

```
      function touch(x1,y1,width1,height1,x2,y2,width2,height2){
        if( x1 + width1 > x2 && x2 + width2 > x1 && y1 + height1 > y2 && 
        y2 + height2 > y1){
          if( y1 + height1 > y2 && y2 + 20 > y1 + height1 )
          {console.log('touch down');plyr.pos[1] = y2-plyr.height;}
          else if( y2 + height2 > y1 && y1 + 20 > y2 + height2)
          {console.log('touch up');plyr.pos[1] = y2+height2;}
          else if( x1 + width1 > x2 && x2 + 20 > x1 + width1)
          {console.log('touch right');plyr.pos[0] = x2-plyr.width;}
          else if( x2 + width2 > x1 && x1 + 20 > x2 + width2)
          {console.log('touch left');plyr.pos[0] = x2+plyr.width;}
        }
      }
```